# Row loop inside different columns

Tags: php, loop, columns

[image: Help need to loop the row]

Help to create a wordpress loop with the row inside different columns from 2 categories

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.